# How do I train two sets of data given both files separately?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-classification

I am doing a project in which I need to estimate the age of an individual, given an X-Ray of their hand. I am given a testing set, which contains a large collection of images (in a folder on my computer), all NUMBERED, and I am also given a CSV file that corresponds each image number with 2 pieces of information: the age(in months), as well as whether the individual is male (this is given as "true" or "false." Also, I believe I have successfully imported both of these files into python(the image folder, as well as the CSV file)

I have looked at many TensorFlow tutorials, but I am struggling to figure out how I can associate the image numbers together, as well as train the data set. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

I have attached blocks of my code, as well as how the data is presented to me, up until this point.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, InputLayer, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import random 
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

--This simply imports libraries that I use, or anticipate using later on.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
train_images=r'/Users/FOLDER/downloads/Boneage_competition/training_dataset/boneage-training-dataset'
for i in range(5):
    file = random.choice(os.listdir(train_images))
    image_path= os.path.join(train_images, file)
    img=mpimg.imread(image_path)
    ax=plt.subplot(1,5,i+1)
    ax.title.set_text(file)
    plt.imshow(img)
```

-- This successfully imports the image folder, as well as prints 5 random images to test if the importing worked.

[This screenshot provides an example of how the pictures are depicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjZvb.png)

```
IMG_WIDTH=200
IMG_HEIGHT=200
img_folder=r'/Users/FOLDER/downloads/Boneage_competition/training_dataset/'
```

-- I believe this resizes all the images to the specified dimensions

```
label_file = '/Users/FOLDER/downloads/train.csv'

train_labels = pd.read_csv (r'/Users/FOLDER/downloads/train.csv')

print (train_labels)
```

-- This successfully imports the data from the CSV file, and prints it, to make sure it worked.

If you have any ideas on how to connect these two datasets and train the data, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is simple create a map between the image_data and the label. After that you can create two lists/np.array and use the same to pass the train and label info to you model. Following code should help in getting the same.

```
import os 
import glob
dic = {}
# assuming you have .png format files else change the same into the glob statement
train_images='/Users/FOLDER/downloads/Boneage_competition/training_dataset/boneage-training-dataset'

for file in glob.glob(train_images+'/*.png'):
    b_name = os.path.basename(file).split('.')[0]
    dic[b_name] = mpimg.imread(file)


dic_label_match = {}
label_file = '/Users/FOLDER/downloads/train.csv'
train_labels = pd.read_csv (r'/Users/rkrishna/downloads/train.csv')
for i in range(len(train_labels)):
    # given your first column is age and image no starts from 1
    dic_label_match[i+1] =  str(train_labels.iloc[i][0])
    # you can use the below line too
    # dic_label_match[i+1] =  str(train_labels.iloc[i][age])

# now you have dict with keys and values 
# create two lists / arrays and you can pass the same to the keram model

train_x = []
label_ = []

for val in dic:
    if val in dic and val in dic_label_match:
        train_x.append(dic[val])
        label_.append(dic_label_match[val])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for you help. In my image folder, the numbering starts from 1377, so I simply changed [i+1] to [i+1377](please do tell me if this is wrong). I have since ran the code multiple times, and I am always getting an error message that corresponds to a certain image/csv associate. eg Error: 4392. How can I fix this? I have been manually deleting those files from the data set (saving them in a different folder) as well as manually editing them out of the csv file(saving them as well).

Comment: [i+1] to [i+377] should work can you tell me the complete error and line at which you are getting is it while reading images are csv ?

Comment: The complete error message is: 

`KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-f611419c60cd> in <module>
     27 for val in dic:
     28     train_x.append(dic[val])
---> 29     label_.append(dic_label_match[val])

KeyError: '10692'`

Comment: it is saying it is not able to find the given key I have updated the answer . you will not get error bt you may miss some of the images and labels have a look at them and read a little about dic in Python